# java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException while deleting the file in java

Tags: java

while deleting the file i am getting java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException below is my code sinippet.The issue her is it is getting called multiple time the same file which got deleted.

```
public static synchronized void deleteFiles(File[] files) {
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            deleteFiles(Objects.requireNonNull(file.listFiles())); // Calls same method again.
        } else if(file.getAbsoluteFile().exists()) {
            System.out.println("SJ================ before deleting");
            file.delete();
        }
    }   
}
```

Here's the stacktrace

```
 java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/ruchitha/Documents/Project_Banyan/DynamicCAError/D:/Project/Project_Banyan/Dynamic_error_files/cpr/ottcConfig/IS20/OTTC/ottc_BWA_eng.properties
     at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
     at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
     at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
```

Comment: And how you get list of files which have to be deleted?

Comment: Hey, please post the actual stack trace.

Comment: File[] files = outputFolderLocation.toFile().listFiles(); @Lemmy

Comment: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/ruchitha/Documents/Project_Banyan/DynamicCAError/D:/Project/Project_Banyan/Dynamic_error_files/cpr/ottcConfig/IS20/OTTC/ottc_BWA_eng.properties
 at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
 at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
 at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)

Comment: I just wonder why you code "if(file.getAbsoluteFile().exists())" and not "if (file.exists())" ?

Comment: i used both and did not work @Joe

Comment: Your stack trace is incomplete - it shows only the three lower-level calls. You need to see which part of _your application_ is causing the exception. Then you'll realise that it's not the code you posted, because the exception is from java.nio but your code only uses java.io.

Answer (score 0):

The file you passed into that function really can not exist, as it contains invalid characters:
`..._Banyan/DynamicCAError/D:/Project/Project`
Problem can be found here: ^

Colons are not allowed in directory- and filenames. Make sure you pass correct files into your function.

Comment: Colons _are_ allowed in directory and file names on Linux and other operating systems.